# How to apply different style to Wordpress wp_nav_menu()

Tags: php, wordpress, menubar

I am using Wordpress 3.0.Is it possible to apply different style class to wordpress wp_nav_menu()?
Currently five pages for me and I would like to apply in following order.

```
<ul>
      <h2>
        <li><a href="#">Example1</a> </li>
      </h2>
      <span>
      <li><a href="#">Example2</a></li>
      </span>
      <h4>
        <li><a href="#">Example3</a></li>
      </h4>
      <h3>
        <li><a href="#">Example4</a></li>
      </h3>
      <h5>
        <li><a href="#">Example5</a></li>
      </h5>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

that isn't semantically correct html - perhaps you want to add a class to each li instead?

WP adds classes to its generated LIs like so:

`page_item page-item-27`

where the number is related to the ID of the article/page.

css:

```
.page-items-27 {
    color:#fff;
    background:blue;
    font-size:14px;
    // etc
}
```